# UWP toolkit dropshadow disappear

Tags: c#, uwp, shadow, windows-community-toolkit

I am using UWP toolkit's dropshadow. There is a gridview. Each item in gridview has it's own shadow panel. Items are resizing automatically on resize of gridview.

The problem is that on some sizes the shadow just disappears. And when I resize again it comes back. And when I am resizing the window it looks like flickering.

I have tried on resize to change the shadow visibility, opacity...no luck.

Is there any way to force redraw/invalidate the shadow panel?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a bug.

Post this issue in https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues. They will help you out.

**Edit:**

Issue has been started in UWPCommunityToolkit regarding this issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/issues/1111